# Huge latency observed while committing transacted persistent AMQ messages

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have the following AMQ consumer configuration file which tries to consume 'persistent' messages from the queue. Also, the messages are 'transacted' (as I need to rollback if a message can't be processed in an expected way).

I see a problem with this configuration:
 Whenever the consumer calls session.commit() after consuming the message, I see the commit call taking ~8 seconds to come out. I believe this is not expected.

Can someone point me if I have any issues with the below config?

```
  <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="simpleMessageListener" class="listener.StompSpringListener"  scope="prototype" />

  <bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <property name="physicalName" value="JOBS.notifications"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="poolMessageListener" class="org.springframework.aop.target.CommonsPoolTargetSource">
    <property name="targetBeanName" value="simpleMessageListener"/>
    <property name="maxSize" value="200"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="messageListenerBean" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetSource" ref="poolMessageListener"/>
  </bean>

  <jms:listener-container 
         container-type="default" 
         connection-factory="amqConnectionFactory" 
         acknowledge="transacted" 
         concurrency="200-200"
         cache="consumer"
         prefetch="10">

    <jms:listener destination="JOBS.notifications" ref="messageListenerBean" method="onMessage"/> 
  </jms:listener-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the the [ActiveMQ Spring support](http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html) page. What I can see immediately is that you should be using a `PoolingConnectionFactory` instead of an `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. This will ensure that only a single TCP connection is set up to the broker from your code, and will be shared between polling threads.